# \x Escape in Java?

Tags: java, hex, escaping

I was wondering if there is a similar hex (\x) escape in Java like there is in C++.
For example:

```cpp
char helloworld[] = "\x48\x45\x4C\x4C\x4F\x20\x57\x47\x52\x4C\x44";
printf("%s", helloworld);
```

There is no hex (\x) escape in Java from what it appears so far. Is there an alternative that is just as easy to use without having to concat a bunch of hex numbers together?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Strings in Java are always encoded in UTF-16, so it uses a Unicode escape: `\u0048`. Octal characters are supported as well: `\110`

Answer (score 7):

Note that Unicode escapes are parsed quite early. It can come as a surprise when

```
  String s = "text\u000d\u000a";
```

causes a compiler error because you should have used `"text\015\012"` or `"text\r\n"`

Comment: -1: Octal escapes are allowed in string literals and are not parsed early as you suggest.  The above code snippet works as expected.  See 3.10.6. Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html

Comment: @adrian - you are correct, I got octal escapes and unicode escapes the wrong way around - I'll fix the answer (if possible).

Comment: Why not remove the answer?

Comment: Because it's useful now