# Java - How to put special characters into a String

Tags: java

Java seems to have very good string handling.  Still, I'm having problems with the simplest of problems.  I need to have dynamic strings (they change at run time) so a String type is not a good choice since they are immutable.  So I am using char arrays.  Kind of a pain to setup but at least they are modifiable.  I want to create a string constant with a carriage return/line feed pair in it (or other control characters).  In C/C++ you would just do this:

```
char myString[100];
myString = "This is a string with a CR/LF pair\x0D\x0A";
```

And yes, I know in java you could use a "\r".  And yes, I know that you could use:

```
myString[34] = 0x000D;
myString[35] = 0x000A;
```

And in Java you really cannot use a string literal constant to initialize a char array (can you??).  So how do you initialize a char array is the question?

Comment: It's *really* not clear why you don't want to just use `\r\n`. It's also unclear what the first part of the question has to do with the second...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613759/x-escape-in-java

Comment: Look to Java's StringBuilder class for a class which is cheap to modify as a String.

Comment: Sorry all, I edited the question.  Is there a way to initialize a char array with a literal string constant?  I will look into StringBuilder, that sounds promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
char[] myString = 
   "This is a string with a CR/LF pair\u000D\u000A".toCharArray();
```

if that was the question.

Also, there is StringBuilder to work with mutable Strings (it just wraps a char[]).

Comment: Strings are immutable so I cannot use the String class.

Comment: @Batdude: You can convert between String and char[].

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.ToCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

```
char[] chars = "This is a string\r\n".ToCharArray();
```

You could also use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which is mutable.