# Java using group separator as delimiter

Tags: java, ascii

I have a String that needs to be separated using the Group Separator, which is "0x1E" in hex.

Example:

```
String notFinalized = HelloGuys
String finalized = Hello Guys // here, the delimiter should be 0x1E
```

How can I do this? I tried `Character.toString("0x1E")` but it did not work.

My idea is to convert 0x1E to String, put it in a variable and then to concatenate this variable with the `finalized` string.

Comment: @vincrichaud could you be more specific please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - How to put special characters into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513610/java-how-to-put-special-characters-into-a-string)

Comment: Actually, 0x1E is the Record Separator. The Group Separator is 0x1D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java a char can be seen as a Byte. You could either declare it by the readable way : `char a = '!'` or by a value `char a = 27` or in hex `char a = 0x1E`

After that, you could add the char to your String using some String method (like replace, or idk)

```
char a = 0x1E;
String str = "test";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll('t', Character.toString(a));
```

Edit : Use `Character.toString()` method in this case, cause `replaceAll()` expect String and not char as parameter. `Character.toString()` converts your char to a String using the readable value.

Edit 2 : As mentionned by Tom Blodget in the comments : /!\ a char is not a Byte ! I wrote "can be seen as a Byte" to mean : "it just contains a numeric value as does a Byte, so you can define a char as you define a Byte by giving it a numeric value". But in fact a char goes from `\u0000` to `\uFFFF` and is encoded on 2 Bytes.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Does `String separated = "blabla" + (char) 30 +"asdsadasd"; ` also will work ?

Comment: So is my example much more easier than your code example? Or is yours better? just asking in terms of "clean code"

Comment: @Blnpwr It depends on your case. If you're going to create only one String with 1 or 2 char inserted inside, your way is easier and claer enough to be used. If your going to apply this to a lot of String or to insert a lot of char inside it, it's better to embed this in some line of code to make it clearer or to prevent to re-write the same thing 10 times..

Comment: "In Java a char can be seen as a Byte" is quite misleading. A [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) has a range from '\u0000' to '\uFFFF' (or two bytes, if you want to see it that way).

Comment: @TomBlodget The "can be seen has" was to meant, a char just contain a numeric value as a Byte does (or an int does). It was not to mean the size of the char. But thx for the precision, i'll update my answer accordingly