# String illegal escape charcter

Tags: java, octal

While answering one of the question, I came across this interesting situation.

If I have string like the following, Netbeans does not complain that it's an `illegal start of expression`.

```
String temp="\19825655.";
```

As soon as I remove '1' it complains that it's an `illegal start of expression`.

```
String temp="\9825655.";
```

couldn't figure out the reason for this behavior. Any input would be appreciated.

**Observation:** It seems `\9` and `\8` has special meaning. Only for `\9` and `\8` I am getting `illegal start of expression`. All other combinations it is not complaining.

Comment: You are using an escape sequence for the number which follows. The `\98` is not valid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\1` is an octal escape code. Check it out in the JLS in [Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

Comment: +1 so it is treating it as `\1` and `9825655.` whereas `\12345` would be treated as `\123` and `45`.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so what this means is that the combination `\1` is an escape sequence.  However, to my knowledge it isn't a known escape sequence.

EDIT: OK it's an *octal* number, interesting - [\x Escape in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613759/x-escape-in-java)

Comment: Well, I understood that part, but why \8 and \9 are not?

Comment: @Nambari - The java spec specified that they shouldn't be.  See the link in the other answer.

Comment: It's an octal escape, and octal only allows digits 0-7, so \8 is not a legal octal value.

Comment: Octal is a base-8 counting system (0-7), similar to how binary is a base-2 system, so only 0-1 are valid digits.