# hexadecimal-escape-sequence matching in java

Tags: java, string-matching

I used this [\x Escape in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613759/x-escape-in-java) question and found out the hex escape in java is \u0048 but now I want to do the hex sequence matching using regx in java. This is what I tried but it does not work:

Pattern hex = Pattern.compile("\\u0048([0-9A-Fa-f]+)");

any suggestion?

Comment: Don't (double) escape - use one backslash.

Comment: @BrianRoach: But `\u0048`, with only one backslash, is equivalent to `H`. I don't think that can be what the OP has in mind, because I can't think of any circumstances where that would be desirable.

Comment: Thanks, it seems Brian solution has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
Pattern hex = Pattern.compile("\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");
```

?

Comment: No, that does not work, I am getting number format exception.

Comment: @user1433755: Nah, regexes don't (and can't) raise `NumberFormatException`. You're getting that exception from some other bit of code; perhaps you're calling `Integer.parseInt` or `Integer.valueOf` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am using (char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16) which throws the exception.

Comment: @user1433755: That implies that `m.group(1)` is `null`, which shouldn't be possible with this regex. (It should only be possible when the capture-group is qualified by `?` or `*` or the like -- something that allows the pattern as a whole to match but a specific capture-group to *not* match.) Can you post the entire code-snippet (as well as the input that it's operating on)?

Comment: Pattern hex = Pattern.compile("\u0048([0-9A-Fa-f]+)");
       Matcher m = hex.matcher(text);
      if (m.find() && m.start() == 0) {
          ch = (char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16); 
      }

Comment: @user1433755: How come your pattern isn't the same as the one in my answer?

Comment: I just pasted the changed one. When I tried yours, the pattern was the same.