# What kind of string uses prefix \x and how to read it

Tags: java, string, unicode, encoding

I have a string like this

```
"\x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL"
```

when i put it in browser console, it automatically becomes something else:

```
"\x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL"
"'ö,úìHL"
```

if I do `chatAt(x)` over this string, I get:

```
"\x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL".charAt(0)
"'"
"\x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL".charAt(1)
""
"\x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL".charAt(2)
"ö"
```

which IS what I want.

Now I want to implement a Java program that reads the string the same way as in browser.

The problem is, Java does not recognize the way this string is encoded. Instead, it treats it as a normal string:

```
"\\x27\\x18\\xf6,\\x03\\x12\\x8e\\xfa\\xec\\x11\\x0dHL".charAt(0) == '\'
"\\x27\\x18\\xf6,\\x03\\x12\\x8e\\xfa\\xec\\x11\\x0dHL".charAt(1) == 'x'
"\\x27\\x18\\xf6,\\x03\\x12\\x8e\\xfa\\xec\\x11\\x0dHL".charAt(2) == '2'
```

What kind of encoding this string is encoded? What kind of encoding uses prefix `\x`?
Is there a way to read it properly (get the same result as in browser)?

update: I found a solution -> i guess it is not the best, but it works for me:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\x27\\x18\\xf6,\\x03\\x12\\x8e\\xfa\\xec\\x11\\x0dHL".replace("\\x", "\\u00"))
```

thank you all for your replies :)
especially Ricardo Cacheira

Thank you

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613759/x-escape-in-java) might helpful?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\x03` is the ASCII hexadecimal value of char

so this: `"\x30\x31"` is the same as : `"01"`

see that page: http://www.asciitable.com

Another thing is when you copy your string without quotation marks your **IDE** converts any `\` to `\\`

Java String uses unicode escape so this: `"\x30\0x31"` in java is: `"\u0030\u0031"`;

you can't use these escape sequence in Java String `\u000a AND \u000d` you should convert it respectively to `\r AND \n`

So this `"\u0027\u0018\u00f6,\u0003\u0012\u008e\u00fa\u00ec\u0011\rHL"` is the conversion for Java of this: `"\x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL"`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there an easy way to read a string with ascii encoding?

Comment: hmm. i guess i mean converting it to a normal utf-16 string where

string.charAt(1) == 'ö'

Comment: are you saying, if i replacing all \x by \u00 will solve my problem?

Comment: hmm. i think i am almost there

System.out.println("\\x27\\x18\\xf6,\\x03\\x12\\x8e\\xfa\\xec\\x11\\x0dHL".replaceAll("\\\\x", "\\\\u00"))

it shows \u0027\u0018\u00f6,\u0003\u0012\u008e\u00fa\u00ec\u0011\u000dHL in the console

Comment: hmm.. my ide won't allow me to type in \x27.... i guess it knows i mean \x27 when i type in \\x27

Comment: first one gives me: \x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL in the console,

the second one gives me: 'ö,úìHL‌​, which is what i want


"\u0027\u0018\u00f6".equals("\\x27\\x18\\xf6".replace("\\x", "\\u00")) == false  <=== any idea why?

Comment: `"\u0031"` will output: `0` and "\\u031" will output: `\u0031` because "\\" is a escape sequence

Comment: i guess the only question left is how to convert it to the version that java accepts i.e. \u00f6  etc

Comment: check my answer last line: This `"\u0027\u0018\u00f6,\u0003\u0012\u008e\u00fa\u00ec\u0011\rHL"` is the conversion for Java of : `"\x27\x18\xf6,\x03\x12\x8e\xfa\xec\x11\x0dHL"`

Comment: i saw it and i just checked. you are right about it. but i still don't know how to programmatically convert the first one into the second one

Comment: what you means with programmatically? What you want to do?

Comment: string a = "\x30\x31";
string b = magic(a);
system.out.print(b); ---> shows '01' <---- i need the magic() :P

Comment: you an't use that on java: `string a = "\x30\x31";` you should use `string a = "\u0030\u0031";`  and with that `system.out.print(b);` you will see: `01`, This is a simple magic ... lol

Comment: i know. but i am receiving some string like "\x30\x31". i don't want to use it. but because someone is sending me this, i have to write something that translates it

Comment: you should been receiving this: "\\x30\\x31", then you need to implement a string parser that makes the conversion !

Answer (score 1):

apache commons provides a helper for this:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(...)
```

**Unescapes any Java literals found in the String. For example, it will turn a sequence of '\' and 'n' into a newline character, unless the '\' is preceded by another '\'.**