# How to match Unicode code points greater then \uFFFF in regex string without Java 7?

Tags: regex, escaping, hex, java-6

Here is my regex:

```
(?x)(?:[A-Za-z:_] | [\\xC0-\\xD6]| [\\xD8-\\xF6] | [\\xF8-\\x{2FF}] | [\\x{370}-\\x{37D}] | [\\x{37F}-\\x{1FFF}] | [\\x{200C}-\\x{200D}] | [\\x{2070}-\\x{218F}] | [\\x{2C00}-\\x{2FEF}] | [\\x{3001}-\\x{D7FF}] | [\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}] | [\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFFD}] | [\\x{10000}-\\x{EFFFF}])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Java refuses to compile it. It raises this exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal hexadecimal escape sequence near index 68
^/((?:(?x)(?:(?x)(?:[A-Za-z:_] | [\xC0-\xD6]| [\xD8-\xF6] | [\xF8-\x{2FF}]...
                                                                    ^
```

What's wrong?

**Java 6**

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613759/x-escape-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve my issue:

```
String regex = "(?x)" + 
       "(?:" + 
       "[A-Za-z:_]        |" + 
       "[\\xC0-\\xD6]     |" + 
       "[\\xD8-\\xF6]     |" + 
       "[\\xF8-\\u02FF]   |" + 
       "[\\u0370-\\u037D] |" + 
       "[\\u037F-\\u1FFF] |" + 
       "[\\u200C-\\u200D] |" + 
       "[\\u2070-\\u218F] |" + 
       "[\\u2C00-\\u2FEF] |" + 
       "[\\u3001-\\uD7FF] |" + 
       "[\\uF900-\\uFDCF] |" + 
       "[\\uFDF0-\\uFFFD] |" + 
       "[\ud800\udc00-\udb7f\udfff]" + 
 )";
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Reference:

- [Unicode code points > \uFFFF in string literals (regex)?](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Unicode-code-points-gt-uFFFF-in-string-literals-regex-td5105310.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `\x{h...h}` notation, with curly brackets and a non-fixed number of hex digits, wasn't added to `java.util.regex.Pattern` until Java 7:

- [Java 6 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [Java 7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

(Search the page for `\x{`. Only the latter link has it.)

Instead, you'll need to use the `\uhhhh` notation: `[\\xF8-\\u02FF]`.

However, `\uhhhh` denotes a UTF-16 code unit, i.e. a Java `char`, rather than a full Unicode codepoint, so the last part of your regex — `[\\x{10000}-\\x{EFFFF}]` — is trickier to translate. I think that Java 6 regexes operate entirely on code units, such that you'd actually need to treat it as two code units: `[\\uD800-\\uDB7F][\\uDC00-\\uDFFF]` (where `[\\uD800-\\uDB7F]` is the relevant subrange of the "high" surrogates, and `[\\uDC00-\\uDFFF]` is the entire range of "low" surrogates; fortunately U+EFFFF comes right at the end of a range of codepoints with the the same high surrogate, or else you'd need to do something even more complicated). (**Disclaimer:** not tested.)

Comment: Do you have any solution for translating this: `[\\x{10000}-\\x{EFFFF}]` ?

Comment: @Stephan: I'm not sure. I've edited my answer to give a possible solution, but I have not tested it.

Comment: I have found a guy that had the same problem like me. I found his solution here: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Unicode-code-points-gt-uFFFF-in-string-literals-regex-td5105310.html. Thanks for your help though ;)

Answer (score 0):

The BNF graph applies only to Java 7 and up. For Java 6, Java RegExp, `\x` expects exactly two hex digits afterwards, no more and no less. If you need to match Unicode, use `\u` followed by exactly four hex digits.

In your case, that would be `... [\xF8-\u02FF] ...`, etc.

The reason for this is that Java RegExp doesn't use a pattern as a placeholder for a character. Instead, the Java compiler creates Unicode code points and collects them in a Unicode string which is then passed to the RegExp tool. Therefore, the RegExp tool never sees `\x` or `\u` (and it's also the reason why you get a compile error for this comment: `// See c:\User\...`)

For Unicode code points > `0xFFFF`, you need to use [surrogate pairs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode). You can create them with `Character.toChars()`. `Character.toChars(0x10000)` creates the two `char`s which represent `\\x{10000}`.

Comment: Do you have any clue for translating this: `[\\x{10000}-\\x{EFFFF}]` ?

Comment: Those codes don't map to 16bit Unicode code points. You will need to use something called "[surrogate pairs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode)". You can use `Character.toChars(0x10000)` to create the two `char`s which represent `\\x{10000}`.