# how to convert \x string to binary and send via socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have this kind of String in Java

```
String java_str = "\x00\x00\x00@\x02\t\x01\x00\******
```

As you can see there are mixed binary and text data.
When I'm sending this string by socket via python
example code

```
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
clientSocket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 11111));
clientSocket.send(bin_data.encode());
```

I'm receiving this binary data
[image]

How can I use Java socket to send the data to the server to receive binary data not a string like this

[image]

Comment: Show us the Java code that you are using to get that screenshot.

Comment: @StephenC
`
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9091);
        OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        String s = "\\x00\\x00\\x00@\\x02\\t\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\n";
        socketOutputStream.write(s.getBytes("ASCII"));
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string in your question is not valid Java:

```
String java_str = "\x00\x00\x00@\x02\t\x01\x00\...";
```

because `\x` is not a valid Java string escape.

Your actual Java code (from the comment) is apparently this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9091); 
OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); 
String s = "\\x00\\x00\\x00@\\x02\\t\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00..."; 
socketOutputStream.write(s.getBytes("ASCII"));
```

What you have actually done there is to escape the backslashes.  So the string literal actually contains literal backslashes, `x` characters and so on.  (Which is what you are seeing in the packet dump.)

The way to express an arbitrary Unicode codepoint (for example the `NUL` or `U+0000` codepoint) in a Java string literal is to use Java's Unicode escape syntax; e.g. `\u0000`.

```
String s = "\u0000\u0000\u0000@\u0002\t\u0001\u0000\u0000...";
```

See [\x Escape in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613759)

---

In this case, a better alternative would be to represent the data as a byte array; e.g.

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, '@', 2, '\t', 1, 0, ...};
```

It is more readable, and conceptually cleaner to express binary
data as binary rather than encoding it as text and converting it
to binary.

(But note that you will need to use `(byte)` type casts for any codes between `0x80` and `0xff` and any non-constant expressions in the array initializer.  That is because the Java `byte` type is signed ...)

---

If you have a Java string that contains explicit (C / C++ ?) `\xnn` sequences, you could convert that to a regular string with some custom code.  It is a bit tedious, but the coding is fairly straightforward ... if you have written a lexer by hand before.

Note that the commonly used the Apache Commons `StringEscapeUtils` ([javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html)) class doesn't work here.  `StringEscapeUtils` implements de-escaping of (strict) Java string literal syntax, and Java doesn't recognize `\xnn` escapes in Strings.   (`StringEscapeUtils` doesn't even handle `\u` ... which is technically correct, though unexpected.)